# Total number of hours uploaded by YouTube Channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

Is it possible to know how many hours of video is uploaded by YouTube user without counting?

I can see number of videos but how do I know how many hours is it going to take to finish watching all the videos in that channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES, it is possible and it is usually fairly simple.
NO, this is not a native feature within YouTube (anymore). 
The only issue you may run in to using this method, is that the tool will only analyze up to 1,000 videos. If that is the case - [see below]
[**NOTE**]
Before you begin, you'll want to find the number of videos on the channel. If you already know how to do this, skip to the section below titled **"HOW"**.
 Otherwise, you may locate the total number of videos by doing the following:
- Go to the channel homepage and scroll to uploads. Click "Play All". A playlist wil appear, and at the very top of that list you will see your current video number, and how many are total - for example: 10/155 
- Alternatively, you may just locate the channel elsewhere and hover over its name (Without actually clicking and going to the page). After two seconds, the namecard will appear and it will show the channel, subscriber info, and the total number of videos. Take note of this number and proceed to the section below.

[**HOW**] 
*First, go ahead and open a tab in your browser and navigate to http://youtube-playlist-analyzer.appspot.com/ 
*Now, going back to your YouTube tab, you'll want to locate the Channel for which you will be getting analytical information. Once there, it will be easiest for you to simply 'copy' + 'paste' ONLY the channel URL.
  *Then, once you have it, go to the Analyzer tab you opened and just paste the Channel URL into the field listed to do so. 
 **Make sure you also select the option 'Channel URL' - otherwise you will get an error.** 
*Lastly, go ahead and choose the **MAXIMUM** number of videos the page will have, up to 1000. This is where the "Number of total videos" comes into play. If you did not get the exact number, you may estimate. 
Keep in mind, if you are making an estimate, this may or may not have an effect on your total time in the results, depending on how closely you estimated.

**[RESULTS]** 
The page may seem to freeze while finding the information. Please be patient because it takes a minute to tabulate. This is especially true with slow internet connections as well as Channels \ Playlists including a high number of total videos. 
 You will have an abundance of ways by which to see the end results - INCLUDING an option to actually see the time of each individual video.
 For your specific question, I would direct you to use the default view and just find the heading 'TOTAL DURATION". If you cannot see where it is, CTRL+F and type TOTAL in the search box. You should then be directed to the exact location of the cumulative length of the channels videos.
 ***I hope this could be of use to alot of people. I have seen this question several times and have tested this quite a bit. Feel free to contact me if something is not working, because I will be more than happy to assist you if my guide is inaccurate in any way!***

**[MORE THAN 1000 VIDEOS]**  
 Depending on how many videos the channels has, you may be able to Google a similar tool that may process over 1000 at a time. You may ALSO do it a slightly more complicated way - but this would most likely only appeal to someone who is VERY intent on finding the exact time of the videos...If you are one of those people, follow along here: 
 **FIRST** 
Go to the channel and click on UPLOADS.
Once the page loads, sort the videos from OLDEST to NEWEST.
 **This is because the very first video on a channel will have the value of 1**
 Once located, click that video.
Once the page opens, proceed to the address bar of the browser, and **without deleting anything from the address bar** add this to the current URL:
 
&feature=mfu_in_order&list=UL 
 Once youve hit 'Enter' the page will load a playlist. That playlist will have EVERY video that the page currently has.
 This is the most difficult part because it isnt a very up-front process....
 **Scroll to the video listed as video 1,000 in the playlist.** 
 *-Right-click (or center-click) so that the video opens in a new tab.* 
-Go ahead and append the EXACT same thing to the URL of the 1000th video and hit enter. 
 **Once again, here is what you will be adding to the URL**
 &feature=mfu_in_order&list=UL 
 **Once it loads, you should have every single video in a playlist, but NOW the playlist will be listing all videos beginning with #1000 and ending at the newest video from that page.
  You will now have to put the first URL (videos 1-1000) into the analyzer first - but this time, you are going to need to play around with the options in the drop down box, because it may not work as a "CHANNEL URL", because it is technically a type of playlist. 

 **If there are 2000 or more videos...**
 Just repeat it all again, in increments of 1000.

Comment: Wow awesome. That's well explained. Thanks for your time and response, Austin. :)

Comment: No problem! Hopefully you were able to figure it out :)

Comment: It looks like the Youtube Playlist Analyzer is still active, but the new URL is https://ytplaylist-len.us